# Call a function from a directive to the controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I am trying to implement a simple comment writing from client to server using angular.
Here is the HTML for the comment form:

```
<form  id="commentsForm" name="commentsForm" ng-submit="submitComment()">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Post a comment</legend>
    <div class="form-group comment-group">
      <label for="comment" class="control-label">Comment</label>
      <div class="control-field">
        <textarea class="form-control" cols="30" rows="5" name="comment" id="comment-textarea" tabindex="3" ng-model="c.comment" required></textarea>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group button-group">
      <div class="control-field">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-comment" tabindex="4" >Post comment</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

And the controller I use with the `"submitComment()"` function:

```
'use strict';
// inject scope, services (CommentService)
//

angular.module('mean.groups').controller('CommentsCtrl', ['$scope','Global', 'CommentsService', function($scope, CommentsService) {
    $scope.c = {};
    console.log("controller is online");
    $scope.submitComment = function (comment) {
        console.log("activted submit comment function");
        var postCommentData = {};
        postCommentData.postingTime = new Date();
        postCommentData.commentData = $scope.c.comment;
        console.log("in controller:" + postCommentData);
        CommentsService.postComment(postCommentData)
            .then(function () {
                $scope.commentsForm.$setPristine();
                $scope.c = {};
                console.log('posted');
            });
    };
}]);
```

And the directive I use wrap the html:

```
'use strict';
angular.module('mean.directives').directive('commentForm', function() {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            templateUrl: 'comments/views/comment-form.html',
            controller: 'CommentsCtrl',
            controllerAs: 'commentsForm'
        }
    });
```

The service I use is a standard `http.post` service but I don't understand why the console.log() in the controller function is not triggered with the comment.
Thanks.

Comment: you appear to be mixing styles here.  Your controller is using the `$scope` syntax, while you directive is declared with the `controllerAs` syntax.  you should choose one or the other.

Comment: choose the $scope syntax, can you show me the places I need to change to match it?

Comment: @ItsikMauyhas, can you provide sample plunkr?

Comment: Yes http://jsfiddle.net/Lh12b5z4 - all I need is to call the submitComment function in the controller with the comment the user had left.

Comment: you do somethin strange: say `'$scope','Global', 'CommentsService'` but in function `function($scope, CommentsService)` so inside function `CommentsService` would be refers to `Global`

Answer (score 1):

You aren't using the controller, to use the controller add the controllerAs object before the functions.

```
<form  id="commentsForm" name="commentsForm" ng-submit="commentsForm.submitComment()">
<fieldset>
<legend>Post a comment</legend>
<div class="form-group comment-group">
  <label for="comment" class="control-label">Comment</label>
  <div class="control-field">
    <textarea class="form-control" cols="30" rows="5" name="comment" id="comment-textarea" tabindex="3" ng-model="commentsForm.c.comment" required></textarea>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group button-group">
  <div class="control-field">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-comment" tabindex="4" >Post comment</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the answer, I just add :

```
 link: function($scope, element, attrs) {
 $scope.submitComment = function () {
      //my code logic ...
   }
}
```

And changed the `replace` to false:

```
replace: false;
```